# "Grazie di" oppure "grazie per"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Non riesco a capire quando si debba usare "di" e quando "per" dopo la parola "grazie". Ad esempio, ho letto "grazie della tua correzione", ma anche "grazie per la tua risposta". Sono tutte e due corrette?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sono intercambiabili.

L'unica regola è che, quando c'è un verbo, l'azione deve essere compiuta. Non puoi dire "grazie per chiedere" (è orrendo!) ma piuttosto "grazie per aver chiesto". Vanno bene i verbi all'infinito presente, se e solo se l'azione, pur presente, è compiuta: "grazie di esser qui", "grazie per esser qui".

Locuzioni come "grazie per rispettare le regole", calcate sull'inglese, non sono accettabili in italiano ma debbono essere riformulate ricorrendo ad una qualche perifrasi. Secondo me per esempio "grazie di voler rispettare le regole" è accettabile (dando per scontato che tale volontà sussista): questa però è una mia opinione personale e, come fa notare DaG nel commento, è altamente discutibile; per evitare di far storcere il naso all'interlocutore, a seconda del contesto, può essere raccomandabile trovare una soluzione più condivisa.

Un paio di fonti autorevoli:

- [Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/reggenza-grazie)
- [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_441.html)

Comment: Veramente non vedo grandi differenze tra "grazie per rispettare le regole" e "grazie di voler rispettare le regole". In entrambi i casi si ringrazia per una presunta azione che ancora non si è svolta, e quindi sono entrambi esempi dell'uso calcato dall'inglese di cui parli.

Comment: Grazie di/per la risposta: +1 per la risposta in sé e per la capacità di accettare le opinioni altrui!

Comment: Trovo gradevole la locuzione "grazie di voler" per l'idea sottintesa di una tacita collaborazione che rende le cose più semplici di come sarebbero altrimenti (nell'esempio: senza la consapevole collaborazione di tutti, non si potrebbero far rispettare le regole). Suggerendo che la volontà sia stata tacitamente espressa, l'azione sarebbe da considerarsi compiuta. È chiaramente una forzatura: a rigore lo stesso ragionamento si potrebbe applicare a qualsiasi altro verbo. Eppure "grazie di rispettare" mi suona proprio male mentre "grazie di voler rispettare" mi suona più accettabile.

Comment: L'uso di "grazie" seguito dal verbo dà luogo a notevoli situazioni incerte. Considera "grazie di esistere": è universalmente accettato, c'è pure la canzone di Eros Ramazzotti, ma la persona mica l'ha scelto di esistere, per cosa la ringrazi? Invece "grazie di poter" non va bene affatto, proprio perché la persona non ha scelto di potere; quindi, di nuovo, che ti ringrazi? Eppure, googlando un po', si trovano espressioni, spesso in contesti religiosi, del tipo "ringrazio di poter …" perché c'è l'idea che il privilegio sia concesso dagli dèi, dalla fortuna, dal caso. E l'espressione suona bene!